# Error of embedding Python in C++ : unable to read memory

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to embed Python in VS C++ but I've encountered this error : unable to read memory. The C++ code is

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('./')");
pName = PyBytes_FromString("Test001");
//pName = PyBytes_FromString(argv[1]);
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
```

The pName contains attributes which are "unable to read memory", both for the line commented. So, the PyImport_Import doesn't work as a result, pModule is NULL.
I've set PYTHONPATH in the environment variable and set argv[1] to Test001. The file Test001.py is in the same folder as the .exe. I could not see the problem, I think there are some problems of configuration.

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code with success using Visual Studio 2013 and Python 2.7.
The only issue I had was with the link in debug which required a python27_d.lib and i had to solve the issue using :

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef _DEBUG
#include <python.h>
#define _DEBUG
#else
#include <python.h>
#endif
```

You should also check which version of python you are linking against.

Comment: Thanks for your relpy. I've met this issue as well and I have resolved it. But, where did you put the file Test001.py?? In the same folder with .exe? Any extra config to do??

Comment: I just put it alongside my vcxproj file. 
You can check the value of Working Directory in debugging properties of your project.

Comment: Did you change any other configuration?

Comment: Nope. Just a Test001.py and a main.cpp containing your code in a main function. I ran it by starting debug in VS.
I also tried to run it from command line with something like
`Debug\testprog.exe` and it also worked.
The py file must be in the directory in which you are when running your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try again.

Comment: The problem persists. I've done the following configuration : 1. In Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories, add C:\Python34\include. 2. In Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directory, add C:\Python34\libs. 3. In Linker-> Input, add python34.lib. 4. Put .py with .vcxproj. I still got the error, c++ could not load python!!

Comment: If the value Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Working Directory is set to $(ProjectDir), and your .py file is indeed in your Project Dir, then the error is a difference between Python 2.7 and python 3.4. Unfortunately, I don't have python 3.4 installed, so i cannot check.